# How do I create multiple tags per day in Liquibase?

Tags: sqlite, liquibase

I'm attempting to use Liquibase to manage the backend SQLite database of an appliance.  The idea being that, on install, the application can generate rollback scripts that can be used if the application is uninstalled and replaced with an earlier version.

The issue that comes up is that running a `tagDatabase` changeset will overwrite any tags done earlier in the day.  Checking the [documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/tag_database.html) reveals that the tagging operating runs as the following example SQL:

```
UPDATE DATABASECHANGELOG SET TAG = 'version_1.3' WHERE DATEEXECUTED = (SELECT MAX(DATEEXECUTED) FROM (SELECT DATEEXECUTED FROM DATABASECHANGELOG) AS X);
```

So, is there a way within the bounds of Liquibase of doing multiple tags in a day?  Or do I need to cook up my own SQL for altering the `DATABASECHANGELOG` table?  I'd rather not do the latter as it could well break with future versions of Liquibase.

Comment: I didn't get what do you mean by "The issue that comes up is that running a tagDatabase changeset will overwrite any tags done earlier in the day.". It just marks last executed changeset in database with a tag that you have specified, what is your issue with overwriting?

Comment: My issue is that, in overwriting existing tags, it is no longer possible to generate a rollback against them.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I see looks like in your database DATEEXECUTED is without time (only date). Isn't it possible to change it to a date type with time?
I've seen some discussion here: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/392 looks like a known issue, but in list of databases that they mention in the fix there is no sqllite. 
So have a look at latest version and if it is not fixed there probably it is not supported yet and you need to implement this tag logic yourself using plain sql queries or custom change (http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/custom_change.html).